# The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, scroll

Welcome! Help me please! The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer. During the scroll there is a strong pull the block up and down. How to fix? Help me please. Thank you very much for your help!

```js
$(function() {
var $hor = $("#horizontal");
$("body").css('padding-bottom', $(window).width()*2);
var delta = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  var width = $(window).width();
  var lim = $hor.position().top - (delta) - ($(window).height() - $hor.outerHeight()) / 2;
  delta = Math.min(Math.max(top - lim, 0), width * 2);

  $(".horizontal:first", $hor).css({left : delta});
  $(".horizontal:last", $hor).css({left : -(width*2 - delta)});
  $("body").css({'padding-top': delta, 'padding-bottom': width*2 - delta});
});

});
```

```css
p {
  height: 500px;
}
#horizontal {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 250px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: -100%;
 padding: 20px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal .h_blockquote {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<div id="horizontal">
<div class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer. The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="horizontal">
<div class="h_blockquote">
<div class="h_blockquote_wrap">The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer. The script does not work properly in the browser Internet Explorer.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: We have no idea what *"does not work properly"* means in specific terms or what versions of internet explorer you have tested in

Comment: In all versions of Internet Explorer browser when scrolling block #horizontal and starts the entire page to "jump" up and down.

Comment: Hi, its an old i.e bug but there is a workaround using a jquery scroll plugin, you can read all about it and see details here https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/160 and a fix here  http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Comment: But if you scroll the page using the sidebar, the script would work.

Comment: No one uses IE anymore. If you support IE, then people will use it with your app, and more people using IE = end of the web. SO DON'T FIX  FOR IE, PLEASE 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on `scroll` firing *smoothly* in old browsers or when using jQuery.

The problem is that the event that fires on scroll is allowed to cancel it, so the browser has to complete the event script before appearing to scroll the page - if this takes too long the scroll appears to stutter or hang.

In your script you're calling jQuery methods like `.width()` and `.outerHeight()` and these wrap [underlying methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) that wait for a DOM reflow. They're slow, not incredibly slow, but slow enough that a scroll animation can appear to drop frames or stutter waiting for them. You also change positioning, which also causes a reflow.

Modern browsers have a new feature to handle this: [passive event listeners](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners) - as passive listeners can't cancel the event the browser doesn't have to worry about waiting for them. jQuery [*still* doesn't support them](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871), so it's recommended not to use jQuery for scroll events at all.

However none of those are available to IE - IE's solution to this problem was to *debounce* the event slightly. Multiple scrolls in quick succession would be stacked and only periodically fired, and DOM reflow changes can cause it to fire partly before and partly after. You don't really notice if you drag the slider but scrolling with the wheel appears to jerk when it catches up.

I'd try the following:

- Move all the size checks that don't change between scroll events outside the scroll.
- Change the positioning to be done with [CSS `transform: translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) as this uses the graphics card to do the calculations.

Comment: This problem is not only in the old browsers. And even in the latest version IE.

Comment: @LADYX The latest version of IE is legacy. MS aren't developing IE any more, and IE11 is the last ever version. It's been out of date since Windows 10 launched and the Microsoft switched to Edge as their current/live browser. They'll patch security bugs in IE11 until about 2025, but other than that it's dead - for legacy corporations and unpatched desktops only.

Comment: @LADYX Don't take my word for it. Chris Jackson (MS lead on this sort of thing) [said that IE 11 is "a dead end"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ausoemteam/2016/01/10/older-versions-of-internet-explorer-reach-end-of-support-january-12-2016-part-3/)

Comment: @LADYX meanwhile, passive event listeners are in [preview for Edge and supported by everyone else](https://caniuse.com/#feat=passive-event-listener), current browsers are working on support for ES2017 and a raft of new APIs and IE11 is still stuck in 2013.